# StartIndex cannot be less than zero. - Error when trying to change a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have the following C# code:

```
ArticleContent = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ArticleContent"].ToString();

if (ArticleContent.Length > 260)
{
   ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.IndexOf('.', 250)) + "...";
}
```

The problem here is that I get this error message:

> StartIndex cannot be less than zero.

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hint: what if there is no `.` in your `ArticleContent` string??

Comment: Better search for an existing function that does what you are trying to do. As you can imagine, you're not the first one writing it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are getting that error because there is no `'.'` character on or after index 250, so `IndexOf` returns `-1`.  You then try to remove the character at position `-1` which gives you the error you are seeing.

Also realize that `Remove` only removes *one character at that position*, not *everything after that position*.  What I *suspect* you want is:

```
if (ArticleContent.Length > 260)
{
   int lastPeriod = ArticleContent.LastIndexOf('.');
   if(lastPeriod < 0)
      lastPeriod = 257;  // just replace the last three characters
   ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Substring(0,lastPeriod) + "...";
}
```

That will add ellipses to the string, making sure it is no longer that 260 characters and breaking at a sentence if possible.

Comment: No... it means there is no '.' AFTER 250.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear why it's failing, but what exactly are you trying to do?  If it's simply to truncate a string to a particular length and indicating the truncation, I might suggest the extension method listed below.  It's usage is simply:

```
ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Truncate(250);
```

Truncate extension method:

```
public static string Truncate(this string pThis, int pLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pThis))
        return pThis;

    if (0 >= pLength)
        return string.Empty;

    var lTruncatedString = pThis;
    const string lEllipses = @"…";

    if (pThis.Length > pLength)
    {
        var lSubstringLength = Math.Max(pLength - lEllipses.Length, 0);
        lTruncatedString = pThis.Substring(0, lSubstringLength) + lEllipses;
        if (lTruncatedString.Length > pLength)
            lTruncatedString = lTruncatedString.Substring(0, pLength);
    }

    return lTruncatedString;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for the nice suggestion. +1 for the Star Wars-reference in your username. -1 for the use of hungarian notation.

Comment: I made an edit to your post. Please read [this post on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).

Answer (score 1):

If the below can't find the '.' it will return -1 which will not be valid for the RemoveAt

```
ArticleContent.IndexOf('.', 250)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others wrote - when your `ArticleContent` has no '.' character - method `.Remove()` will return -1.

I suggest to add one more condition in your `if`:

```
if (ArticleContent.Length > 260 && ArticleContent.Contains('.'))
{
    ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.IndexOf('.', 250)) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Source of error:** `'.'` does not appear after index 250. The `IndexOf` method returns -1 in this case.

While others have just identified the source of the error, I will also post a fix to your problem.

**Solution:** Use the `LastIndexOf` method:

```
if (ArticleContent.Length > 260)
{
   if (ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.LastIndexOf('.') != -1)
   {
       ArticleContent = String.Concat(ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.LastIndexOf('.')), "...");
   }
   else
   {
       ArticleContent = String.Concat(ArticleContent.Substring(0, 257), "...")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that there is no . after position 250. You need to check first:

```
ArticleContent = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ArticleContent"].ToString();

var periodPosition = ArticleContent.IndexOf('.', 250);
if (ArticleContent.Length > 260 && periodPosition >= 0)
{
   ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.IndexOf('.', 250)) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArticleContent = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ArticleContent"].ToString();
if (ArticleContent.Length > 260)
{
    if (ArticleContent.Substring(250).Contains("."))
    {
        ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.IndexOf('.', 250)) + "...";
    }
    else
    {
        ArticleContent = ArticleContent.Remove(ArticleContent.Substring(0, 250)) + "...";
    }
}
```